# how to use (np.busday_count) with pandas.core.series.Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

I want to calculate the business days between two columns type pandas.core.series.Series

between **Received date** and **complete date** #*business days only*
I was trying to use np.busday_count(Received date,complete date,weekmask= "Fri Sat")
but I was getting :

> TypeError: Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from
>   dtype('M8[us]') to dtype('M8[D]') according to the rule 'safe'

Here is part of my dataframe:

```
     Received   Complete
0  2018-09-10 2018-09-25
1  2018-07-16 2018-08-13
2  2018-07-05 2018-07-11
3  2018-07-05 2018-07-23
4  2018-07-26 2018-08-14
5  2018-07-04 2018-08-28
6  2018-07-05 2018-07-10
7  2018-07-05 2018-07-10
8  2018-07-05 2018-07-22
9  2018-07-05 2018-07-22
10 2018-07-05 2018-07-19
```

Comment: Could you paste a part of the pandas dataframe here?

Comment: I've edited the post Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Where is complete date?

Comment: I updated the complete date 
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe I have an issue with the data also 
how can i make sure that all the dates are in the same format so I will not get an error when I convert it 
is there anyway to clean the dates data ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As indicated in the error, convert to `'datetime64[D]'` *before* using `np.busday_count`:

```
res = np.busday_count(df['Received'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'),
                      df['Complete'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'),
                      weekmask= "Fri Sat")

# array([ 4,  8,  2,  6,  6, 16,  2,  2,  6,  6,  4], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanks it make sense but I'm working on xlsx sheet
sorry I didn't mention this in the beginning

Comment: @KhaledKhanfar, CSV is not relevant to my answer (and I've removed it). You just need to make sure `df['Receved']` and `df['Complete']` are `datetime` series.

Comment: Thanks a lot for following up on this 
and the type is datetime
but I'm getting : Error parsing datetime string " 9-4-2018" at position 3
and I've looked into this specific value type and it was datetime :(

Comment: @KhaledKhanfar, Looks like your series is not really `datetime` then. Check `df.dtypes` to confirm. There are *many* questions on SO on how to convert different string formats to `datetime`. It's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: ,Thanks a lot for you help I will look into it :)