# Subtract datetime now from a dataframe column without Saturday and Sunday

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

Currently my script is subtracting my current time with the times that i have in a Dataframe column called "Creation", generating a new column with the days of the difference. I get the difference days with this code:

```
df['Creation']= pandas.to_datetime(df["Creation"],dayfirst="True")

#Generates new column with the days.
df['Difference'] = df.to_datetime('now') - df['Creation']
```

What i want to now is for it to give me the days like hes giving me but dont count the Saturdays and Sundays. How can i do that ?

Comment: so the calculation of `df['Difference']` should *exclude* Saturdays and Sundays, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, give me the days without the Saturdays and Sundays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of `numpy`'s [***busday_count***](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html), Ex:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# some dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Creation': ['2021-03-29', '2021-03-30']})

# make sure we have datetime
df['Creation'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Creation'])

# set now to a fixed date
now = pd.Timestamp('2021-04-05')

# difference in business days, excluding weekends
# need to cast to datetime64[D] dtype so that np.busday_count works
df['busday_diff'] = np.busday_count(df['Creation'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'),
                                    np.repeat(now, df['Creation'].size).astype('datetime64[D]'))

df['busday_diff'] # since I didn't define holidays, potential Easter holiday is excluded:
0    5
1    4
Name: busday_diff, dtype: int64
```

If you need the output to be of dtype `timedelta`, you can easily cast to that via

```
df['busday_diff'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['busday_diff'], unit='d')

df['busday_diff']
0   5 days
1   4 days
Name: busday_diff, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

***Note:*** `np.busday_count` also allows you to set a custom weekmask (exclude days other than Saturday and Sunday) or a list of holidays. See the docs I linked on top.

***Related:*** [Calculate difference between two dates excluding weekends in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57194543/10197418), [how to use (np.busday_count) with pandas.core.series.Series](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54234021/10197418)

Comment: That works, is there a way to not dtype as a int64 but to a timedelta(64)?

Comment: @Ricardoke yup, edited. I think the easiest thing is to just cast to timedelta with `pd.to_timedelta`.